# Query string present in POST after a GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

I'm fairly new in web development, so bear with me if this question appear to be a very basic one.

I have these codes in my Razor page

```html
<form method="get">
    <input type="number" name="Id" />
    <input type="date" name="AddDate" />
    <input type="text" name="Title" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsDone" value="true" />

    <input type="submit" value="GET" />
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="Id" />
    <input type="date" name="AddDate" />
    <input type="text" name="Title" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsDone" value="true" />

    <input type="submit" value="POST" />
</form>
```

And my page model

```cs
public void OnGet(int id, DateTime addDate, string title, bool isDone)
{
}
public void OnPost(int id, DateTime addDate, string title, bool isDone)
{
    // Not empty when POSTed after GET. I suppose the POST will not use query string?
    var q = Request.QueryString;
}
```

When I POST the form after GET, the query string is not empty (from the last GET). The form values are POSTed OK, but the presence of query string in a POST request confuse me.

Did I missed some fundamental HTML concept?

Comment: For those who voted to close this question, mind to share the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I POST the form after GET, the query string is not empty (from the last GET).

By default, the form values are appended to the receiving page's URL as query string values if the GET verb is used.

In Razor pages, if the page name or page handler attribute is omitted, the form will be submitted to the current URL.

> The form values are POSTed OK, but the presence of query string in a POST request confuse me.

If you do not want these query string values for previous GET request are present in your POST handler, you can try to explicitly set `asp-page` attribute with current page model name, like below.

```
<form method="post" asp-page="/Test">
    <input type="number" name="Id" />
    <input type="date" name="AddDate" />
    <input type="text" name="Title" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsDone" value="true" />

    <input type="submit" value="POST" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers treat a form without an `action` (which really should be provided) the same as `action=""` which means: use the current page location. This means it includes the current query-string.

Since you don't want that: specify an explicit `action`